# How to write sex data to the health kit even if HKQuantityTypeForIdentifier isn't available?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I have a HealthKit object with all the proper setup, however I am trying to write to the specific sex data area of health kit, however, I can't find that type in HKQuantityTypeForIdentifier. How do I write sex data to HealthKit in swift? More specifically I am looking to add a data point to the sexual activity data under reproductive health.

Comment: No I mean reproductive health.

Comment: I found something like this in pre-release docs, but I have no idea what it is: HKCategoryTypeIdentifierSexualActivity

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HealthKit_Constants/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Category_Type_Identifiers

Answer (score 0):

The type identifier for sexual activity is `HKCategoryTypeIdentifierSexualActivity` (see `HKTypeIdentifiers.h`).

Comment: How to write HKCategoryTypeIdentifierSexualActivity data in health kit? means which metadata objects we have to set?